# Missing doxygen warning for undocumented enum class constants

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm missing doxygen warnings for undocumented constants within enum classes (C++11).

Here an example:

```
//! Some description here
enum class MyEnumClass : uint32_t
{
  Alpha, //!< Documented!
  Beta,
  Gamma,
};
```

Doxygen throws a warning when I skip the doxygen comment for the enum class (comment above enum class) but not for the constants "Beta" and "Gamma".

I tried to flip some doxygen config parameters but unfortunately without success.

I'm using Doxygen version 1.8.11.
Do you have any idea if it is possible to throw this specific warning and how?

Comment: What makes you think that doxygen is supposed to warn?

Comment: I'm working on a project where we want to assure that every corner of our public API is documented. If a developer missed to document something our Jenkins Job notifies the culprit since doxygen is able to write all warning into a .err file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is currently possible . Note you are also using an older version (current version is 1.8.15 (though still same problem).

Comment: I still want to know why you think doxygen can/should warn. You did explain why you want it to, but not why you think it might/could.

Comment: It should warn me for inconsistency and it should also be able to do that (if you ask me).
If I remove the doxygen comment above the enum class I get the following warning:
warning: Member MyEnumClass (enumeration) of namespace XYZ is not documented.

Comment: I see. So nothing whatsoever supports your desire that doxygen warns on this. You only want it to so much that you think it should obviously have that feature. Did you consider filing a feature request?